# migration creation error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am relatively new to laravel framework.I was going through some tutorials and i tried the following command.

`php artisan make:model User -m`

[image]

Above shows the output that i recieved on the console.I do get that it's something related to the path but how do i resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: Did you run `php artisan make:auth` before you made that model?

Comment: its trying to access the migration that is being made while you run auth command, but you probably did not.

Comment: nope i didnot , should i run that command before dooing this command?

Comment: i tried your command and thhen i did mine , same error

Comment: There is no connection between the two, but when you added the `-m` to create the migration for it, for some reason it tried to access the migration made by the auth command.

Comment: And by the way. i see you are creating a User model, and probably want to create a registration system for your users. i suggest you run that command and save a lot of time.

Comment: how do i create a migration then/

Comment: what would be your suggestion to achieve the same?

Comment: I believe you are on a fresh laravel installation, right? if so... please install a new laravel project and run the auth command first.

Comment: To make a migration you can run `php artisan make:migration THE NAME OF THE MIGRATION`

Comment: I highly recommend that you install a new laravel project first.

Comment: i can do that , i just installed it for learning purposes, is there anyway to uninstall it ? or i just delete the files?

Comment: You just delete the laravel project folder, yes... please tell me after if you made it.

Comment: hey maynee i did it , it didn;t work for me

Comment: i see the same error as before

Comment: Got the solution :D

Comment: check the solution , i answered my own question

Comment: You censored out the folder name in the second picture, but didn't censor out the folder name in the error in the first picture.

Comment: haha opps my bad :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing this :

`php composer.phar dump-autoload`

Then `php artisan make:model User -m`

It would work like a charm and do remember, `composer.phar` should be in the same folder , where the `composer.json` file lies.